# Mongoose - remove array element in update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a JSON in this format:

```
{
   _id:5522ff94a1863450179abd33,
   userName:'bill',
   __v:3,
   friends:[
      {
         _id:55156119ec0b97ec217d8197,
         firstName:'John',
         lastName:'Doe',
         username:'johnDoe'
      },
      {
         _id:5515ce05207842d412c07e03,
         lastName:'Adam',
         firstName:'Foo',
         username:'adamFoo'
      }
   ]
}
```

And I would like to remove whole corresponding subarray. For example I want to remove user John Doe with ID `55156119ec0b97ec217d8197` so the result will be:

```
{
   _id:5522ff94a1863450179abd33,
   userName:'bill',
   __v:3,
   friends:[
      {
         _id:5515ce05207842d412c07e03,
         lastName:'Adam',
         firstName:'Foo',
         username:'adamFoo'
      }
   ]
}
```

So far I have this:

```
exports.delete = function (req, res) {
    var friends = req.friends[0];

    friends.update(
        {'_id': req.body.friendsId},
        {$pull: {'friends.friends': {_id: req.body.friendId}}}, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.json(friends);
            }
        });
};
```

But without result and also I'm not getting any error, it will stay just same as before. `req.body.friendsId` is ID of main array and `req.body.friendId` is ID of specific user which I want to pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your update query to this:

```
exports.delete = function (req, res) {
    var friends = req.friends[0]; // assuming the friends object is your mongodb collection

    friends.update(
        { '_id': req.body.friendsId },
        { $pull: {'friends': { _id: req.body.friendId } } }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.json(friends);
            }
        });
};
```

This will search for documents which have the friends array element `_id` value = `req.body.friendsId` and removes the specific array element from that array using the **`$pull`** operator.

Comment: Thank you very much, problem was in friends object